# Injecting HttpInterceptor to app.module.ts problem in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interceptor in Angular 6. And, I want to inject my app.module.ts. So, I changed **"{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }"** part to **"{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }"** . But, when I change or remove LocationStrategy, then i saw blank page and there is no error in console. What can be reason of this situation?

Providers part of app.module.ts

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true },
    //{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    AuthGuard, GlobalVariables, FormBuilder
  ]
```

loader-interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import {
  HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent,HttpInterceptor,HttpResponse,HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }
  //function which will be called for all http calls
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //how to update the request Parameters
    const updatedRequest = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Some-dummyCode")
    });
    //logging the updated Parameters to browser's console
    console.log("Before making api call : ", updatedRequest);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        event => {
          //logging the http response to browser's console in case of a success
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log("api call success :", event);
          }
        },
        error => {
          //logging the http response to browser's console in case of a failuer
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log("api call error :", event);
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `this._httpService.ukljuciLoader` is true ? did you put the log and check ?

Comment: Try using `routerModule.forRoot(yourRoutes, { useHash: true })` when declaring your routes.

Comment: Also, you don't need to remove your first provider, I don't see why you would do that, the two are uncorrelated.

Comment: I edited my question and convert to interceptor very basic. The problem is also continueing @SunilSingh

Comment: How can I add both of them @trichetriche?

Comment: One after the other ?

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche. I tried with array like 
    { provide: [HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, LocationStrategy], useClass: [HashLocationStrategy, LoaderInterceptor] }. But right way is, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }. It worked

Comment: Well instead of trying out of the blue, try understanding the concept behind providers : on each line, you're creating a dependency, that you override with your custom strategies. Here, you're overriding the default interceptor, and the location strategy : you need two providers, so two lines.